# How to query my Polygon NFTs created on Opensea?

Tags: polygon, opensea, query

sadly I realized, that while querying my assets on Opensea, as well as collections, is feasible through OpenSea Api for Ethereum NFTs, the same is not true for Polygon Collections and NFTs in my wallet. Does somebody know how I can query my OpenSea NFTs on Polygon and return Information like Picture links and so on?

Best regards, John

Answer (score 1):

To find items on Polygon, make sure to check "Polygon" under the "Chains" section on the left panel.

If you want to access through opensea-js API, unfortunately it is not supported yet (as of late 2021). See https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/issues/72

But there is always a workaround if you are a hacky person.

You can analyze the Fetch/XHR request under the Network tab of your browser's dev console. [This](https://opensea.io/assets?search%5Bchains%5D%5B0%5D=MATIC&search%5Bquery%5D=bored%20ape) is an example query that searches for "bored ape" on the polygon network. You can see that it's making POST requests to the GraphQL api endpoint https://api.opensea.io/graphql/ while the page is loading. I think that's enough hint for anyone with webdev experience.

Comment: I sadly fail at reaching the graphql endpoint from my machine...

Comment: Hi, I got to the point of finding this: 
import requests

query = """query OrdersQuery(...}
response = requests.post('https://api.opensea.io/graphql/',
    json={"query": query, "variables": variables}
)
print(response.text)

But I it gives me an error. Any idea how I can send a custom header?